# Managed Metadata -> Export to Excel

Tags: 2013, managed-metadata, 2016

When I export to excel , the results should be altered and exported to excel. 
The reason is such that , I want the Managed Metadata results to be separated into 2 separate columns when I do export to excel ?

> Eg : Managed Metadata has Toyota->Camry , Toyota->Prius , Nisaan ->
>   Rouge - When I do export to excel the results needs to be 2 separate
>   columns.

Also, I want the Managed Metadata column to be set with property Display format: `"Display term label in the field"`

Comment: A workaround could be to do two separate calculated columns which one of them is used to only include the manufacturer and the other to include the model. This is most reliable if you know your manufacturers beforehand (=> `if [column] "car manufacturer a" THEN "car manufacturer a" OR [column]="car manufacturer b" THEN "car manufacturer b" OR` ...)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: When you say Managed Metadata has Toyota -> Camry, etc.  are you saying Camry and Prius are children of Toyota and Rogue is a child of Nissan?  If so, given your requirement to use "Display term label in the field" instead of "Display the entire path to the term in the field" you will not be able to accomplish this with the Export to Excel function from the Ribbon.  If you temporarily change the column to display entire path and then Export to Excel, you can use formulas in Excel to split into two columns.